# Perspective correct interpolation of normal values

Tags: c++, perspective, software-rendering

I'm currently writing a software rasterizer and I'm at the point where I can draw arbitrary triangles with vertex colors and perspective correct texture mapping.
I do point and directional lighting by linearly interpolating the vertex normals and it works fine, only on big triangles you can notice that the lighting is somehow distorted when viewed from a very flat angle.
However, this is only visible when you're particularly looking for it but I was wondering if there is a way to have perspective correction on the normals too.

For the texture coordinates and other stuff this is being done by dividing the value by W or Z. But if you divide a vector by a single number you only change its magnitude, which is useless, as I'm normalizing the vector in the end for the lighting computation.
So, is there a way to do it?